# How do I eliminate the SettingWithCopyWarning while working with pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, warnings

I am using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from pathlib import Path

#%% Specify the path and load the data
path = Path('./../')

# Load the data
data = pd.read_csv(path / 'data/data.csv')
data.loc[:,'Date'] = pd.to_datetime(list(data['Date_x']), format='%Y-%m-%d').date
```

which results in the following warning (essentially due to the last line in the code snippet):

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  data.loc[:,'Date'] = pd.to_datetime(list(data['Date_x']), format='%Y-%m-%d').date
```

I want to write a code such that there is no warning (not by suppressing the warning).
Can anyone help?

---

Comment: `data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date_x'], format='%Y-%m-%d').dt.date `